# Designing Context-Free Grammars for Sets of Strings

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm pretty lost, and would appreciate help or solutions to the following two exercises. I don't really know where to begin or even how to correctly denote a context-free grammar. I have to design CFGs for the following two sets:

> 1) $\{a^ib^jc^k \mid i \neq j \;or\; j \neq k \}$; i.e. the set of strings containing $a$s followed by $b$s followed by $c$s, s.t. there is a different number of $a$s and $b$s or a different number of $c$s and $b$s, or both.

I think I should have something like $S \rightarrow aAbBcC$, where thereafter $A \rightarrow a | A | \epsilon$, and similar for $b,c$, etc. But I don't know how to ensure different numbers of letters in the string, and more generally, I don't know what I'm doing.

> 2) The set of all strings of $a$s and $b$s that are not of the form $ww$, that is, not equal to any string repeated.

Comment: For 1, can you construct a grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k|i>j\}$? Do you know how to take unions of CFGs?

Comment: I do not know how to construct a grammar for $i>j$. I also do not know how to take a union of a CFG, though I can read up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *or* in the first problem should suggest writing the grammar in two parts, one that generates $L_1=\{a^ib^jc^k:i\ne j\}$ and one that generates $L_2=\{a^ib^jc^k:j\ne k\}$. If $S_1$ is the initial symbol for the first grammar, $S_2$ is the initial symbol for the second grammar, and the two grammars have no non-terminal symbols in common, they can be combined to give a grammar for the desired language simply by adding the production $S\to S_1\mid S_2$.

In generating $L_1$ you can generate any number of $c$’s, but you have to make sure that you don’t generate equal numbers of $a$’s and $b$’s. The $c$’s are no problem: we can have a production $S_1\to XC$, where $C$ will generate any number of $c$’s, and $X$ will deal with that $a$’s and $b$’s. We can let $X$ generate any number of matched pairs of $a$’s and $b$’s with the production $X\to aXb$, and then we can switch either to something that generates any positive number of $a$’s or to something that generates any positive number of $b$’s. For instance, the production $X\to Y$ together with $Y\to aY\mid a$ will take care of the words with more $a$’s than $b$’s.

That’s all of the pieces needed for the first problem; all you have to do is finish putting them together.

**Added:** The second problem is solved in [this PDF](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~ztomasze/ics641/ztomaszeA2.pdf): a context-free grammar is given along with a proof that it generates the desired language.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the notation: when you say "by adding the production $S\rightarrow S_1 \mid S_2$", is that the notation I should use? If I am adding - so thinking about unions - why would I use a pipe-symbol?

Comment: @Newb: Because you want $S$ to generate either $S_1$ (and from there a word in $L_1$) or $S_2$ (and from there a word in $L_2$). This is a standard way to form a grammar for the union of two langauges, here for $L_1\cup L_2$. Technically you’re adding two productions, $S\to S_1$ and $S\to S_2$; the pipe symbol is just a way to write both at once.

Comment: I think I managed to do the first one, though I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Could you please have a look and verify my solution? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/546841/98587

Comment: The link to the pdf is broken. The example with the proof from the same author can be found here: http://zach.tomaszewski.name/uh/ics641/ztomaszeA2-slides.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think I managed to do the individual grammars correctly, but I'm not sure if I composed them correctly in the end. Also, am I allowed to have e.g. $C \rightarrow C | c | \epsilon$? (I recall reading something about using epsilons in CFGs...) Do I even need to define the grammar with the $G=\{V,\Sigma, P,S\}$ notation? Please let me know what you think.

**Answer to Problem 1**:

This grammar $L$ is best constructed in two parts: $L_1 = \{a^ib^jc^k|i\neq j\}$, and $L_1 = \{a^ib^jc^k|j\neq k\}$. Let $S_1 \rightarrow L_1$ and $S_2 \rightarrow L_2$. We define that the two grammars do not share any non-terminal symbols, thus we can produce the desired CFG by $S \rightarrow S_1 \mid S_2$.
In $L_1$, we can generate an arbitrary number of $c$s. So let us define $S_1 \rightarrow XC$, where $C \rightarrow C \mid c\mid \epsilon$. Then let us define $X \rightarrow aXb$, which will generate any length of matched $a$s and $b$s. To ensure the  case $i>j$, we also define $X \rightarrow Y$, and let $Y\rightarrow aY | a$. To ensure the case $j>i$, we define $X \rightarrow Z$, and let $Z \rightarrow Zb | b$.

So we define our CFG $L_1$ as such:
$L_1 = (\{S_1,X,Y,Z,C\},\{a,b,c\},P,S_1)$ with production rules:
$S_1 \rightarrow XC$
$C \rightarrow cC \mid \epsilon$
$X \rightarrow aXb$
$X \rightarrow Y$
$Y \rightarrow aY \mid a$
$X \rightarrow Z$
$Z \rightarrow Zb \mid b$

The case for $L_2$ is similar, except for that we can generate an arbitrary number $a$s instead of $c$s. Our CFG $L_2$ can be defined as:
$L_2 = (\{S_2,A,Q,R,S\},\{a,b,c\},P,S_2)$
$S_2 \rightarrow AQ$
$A \rightarrow Aa \mid \epsilon$
$Q \rightarrow bQc$
$Q \rightarrow R$
$R \rightarrow bR \mid b$
$Q \rightarrow S$
$S \rightarrow Sc \mid c$

So to conclude, our CFG $L$ is defined: $L = (\{S,X,Y,Z,C\},\{a,b,c\},P,S)$,and $S \rightarrow S_1 | S_2$

Comment: As this stands this isn’t quite right. First, $L,L_1$, and $L_2$ aren’t symbols in the grammar, so $L\to L_1\mid L_2$ doesn’t make sense; you want $S\to S_1\mid S_2$. Next, you didn’t keep the sets of non-terminal symbols disjoint, and as a result you have a problem: your grammar has productions $X\to aXb$ and $X\to bXc$, which means that it can generate the derivation $$S\Rightarrow S_1\Rightarrow XC\Rightarrow X\Rightarrow aXb\Rightarrow abXcb\Rightarrow abYcb\Rightarrow abacb\;,$$ thereby generating a word not in $L$. You have the same problem with other non-terminals.

Comment: Oh! I thought I could reuse variable names - no such luck! Though on second thought it makes sense that I cannot reuse $X$. I will edit my solution momentarily.

Comment: I've made changes as you suggested. Questions: do I need to include CFG-definitions of the sort $L = (\{S,X,Y,Z,C\},\{a,b,c\},P,S)$? Or is it sufficient to simply describe the production rule? Finally, why does $S\rightarrow S_1 \mid S_2$ 'work'? I haven't fully wrapped my head around $S \rightarrow S_1 | S_2$ and the structure it implies. I'm worried that I might end up with a concatenation of $L_1$ and $L_2$ or something like that.

Comment: You still have a few problems. $C\to C\mid c\mid\epsilon$ generates one $c$ or none; it can’t generate more than one, though it can ‘stutter’ $C\Rightarrow C\Rightarrow C\Rightarrow\ldots$ for as long as you want before either disappearing or turning into a $c$. You want $C\to cC\mid\epsilon$. You have a similar problem with $A$. Otherwise I think that it’s okay, though I might have missed some small error. The productions $S\to S_1\mid S_2$ can’t possibly result in concatenation of a word in $L_1$ with one in $L_2$: that’s the point of keeping the non-terminal symbols in the sub-grammars ...

Comment: In the paper you linked (it's very good, thank you), what does the author mean with $w \in \{a,b\}^+$? Specifically, it is the notation $\{a,b\}^+$ that I am curious about.

Comment: ... distinct. Every derivation must start either $S\Rightarrow S_1$, in which case it stays in the $L_1$ grammar thereafter, or $S\Rightarrow S_2$, in which case it stays in the $L_2$ grammar thereafter. As a result you get either a word in $L_1$ or a word in $L_2$: this construction gives you a grammar for $L_1\cup L_2$.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is a regular expression, $\varphi^+$ is an abbreviation for $\varphi\varphi^*$: where the star lets you concatenate any non-negative number of $\varphi$ words, the plus lets you concatenate any **positive** number of them. It’s the same thing when applied to sets: $\{a,b\}^+$ is the set of non-empty strings of $a$’s and $b$’s, represented by the regular expression $(a\cup b)^+=(a\cup b)(a\cup b)^*$ (or whatever symbol you use instead of $\cup$ for the *or* in your regular expressions).

Comment: That looks much better. Whether you can get away with giving only the productions and the initial symbol instead of giving the complete description depends on the instructor. If in doubt, give the whole thing.

Comment: I think I caught one final mistake. I wrote "to conclude, our CFG $L$ is defined: $L = (\{S,X,Y,Z,C\},\{a,b,c\},P,S)$", but that includes only the variables for $L_1$! I should change that to "to conclude, our CFG $L$ is defined: $L = (\{S,S_1,S_2,X,Y,Z,C,A,Q,R,S\},\{a,b,c\},P,S)$" -- right?

Comment: Yes, you need to list all of the non-terminals.

Comment: Then I think the solution is complete. Hooray! Thank you very much for all your help. I have more questions about formal languages, but I don't want to exhaust you so early in the day.

Comment: You’re welcome.